# Update expression engine channel entry content

Tags: channel-entries, add-on, php, channel-images, api

I'm new to expression engine so my question might not sound right to most people.

I'm trying to update the content for a channel entry but not sure whether it's possible or not.

I checked the [channel fields API](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/api/api-channel-fields.html) but through this API I can only update the structure of the field what I'm trying to achieve is update the data available in it.

For example for a channel called Blog, I've added a custom field 'reference'. This custom field contains a URL. I need to update this URL based on an external API but not sure how.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to update a channel entry is to edit it via the ExpressionEngine administration screens.
If you log into the administration area (usually via a link similar to `https://domain.com/admin.php` but the exact form might change on systems if the developers have done things to make it more obscure).
Once you have logged in you should see options for editing the content of the CMS (what this looks like varies according to which version of EE you are using).
The docum[enter link description here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/getting-started/the-big-picture.html)entation for which ever version of EE you are using should give good guidance on how to edit content - but in your case simply find the entries for channel blog, open the blog entry you are wanting to change, and then paste in the URL to the field you added.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I'm trying to achieve this programmatically. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes! Easiest way is to use the EE Class system, locate your entry, update the value and save. Read up on the Add-on system for EE and there are multiple ways of achieving this - good simple example [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/models/channel-entry.html#examples)

Comment: Oh, thanks a bunch!